# Optional route params?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a route:

```
Route::get('/{slug?}', [
    'as' => 'my-controller',
    'uses' => 'MyController@index'
]);
```

So when I hit:

```
my-domain.dev/some-slug
```

It works, but I thought the question mark made the param optional? I would also like to call the index method when the domain is just:

```
my-domain.dev
```

Comment: Question mark makes param optional. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Comment: What do you mean by optional, the request will still be sent to the same controller action? Do you want it to be forwarded to another controller?

Comment: But the param is not optional, hitting my-domain.dev does not load the MyController@index. I have no other routes defined.

Comment: I want my-domain.dev to go to MyController@index

Comment: This should definitely call the *index()* if you access `my-domain.dev` without a parameter. What is opened instead?

Comment: Its just a blank page, on the index method I have a die('ok') statement so this should show.

Comment: Can you run `php artisan route:list` and add the results to your question.

Comment: Can you provide your controller's index() function?

Comment: Can you remove the `/` in front of the route?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```php
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'my-controller',
    'uses' => 'MyController@index'
]);
Route::get('/{slug?}', [
    'as' => 'my-controller',
    'uses' => 'MyController@index'
]);
```

MyController:

```php
public function index($slug = null) {
    //do stuff if slug is not null
}
```

I am not saying it is the best way to do this, but it does work.